# how to set the default text value on the data-grid view particular column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to define the default text value on data-grid view particular column.If that column can accept only `DateTime` value. And at form load that `DateTime` format should be visible to user.

Comment: Try default(DateTime). It works for double, int. Not sure about DateTime. But give it a try.

Comment: use the `DateTime.TryToParse`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
if (dataGridView1.Columns[i].ValueType == typeof(DateTime))
{
    dataGridView1.Columns[ColumnIndex].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
}
```